# PHP Elasticsearch 7.5 - Painless script condition is not providing proper results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

This is my elasticsearch query. I am trying to get all the documents which meets the condition where if `job_id` is 1 then get documents which has `sourced = 0` else if `job_id` is not 1 then get documents with `sourced = 1`.

But it returns all the documents.

```
[
'script' => 
    ['script' => 
        [
            'lang' => 'painless', 
            'source' => "(doc['job_id'].size() > 0 && doc['job_id'].value !==  params.jid) || (doc['job_id'].size() > 0 && doc['job_id'].value == params.jid && doc['sourced'].value == 0)",
            'params' => ['jid' => 1]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Mapping for referred fields

```
"job_id" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
"sourced" : {
      "type" : "byte"
    },
```

Comment: Can you please share your mappings? your query does not meet the question requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have added mappings for selected fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each document is evaluated by the inline script.

An example (base on your mappings):

**Insert documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "job_id": 1,
  "sourced": 0
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "job_id": 0,
  "sourced": 2
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search (Kibana usage)
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['job_id'].value == params.jid ? doc['sourced'].value == 0 : doc['sourced'].value == 1",
        "params": {
          "jid": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your usage

```
[
'script' => 
    ['script' => 
        [
            'lang' => 'painless', 
            'source' => "doc['job_id'].value == params.jid ? doc['sourced'].value == 0 : doc['sourced'].value == 1",
            'params' => ['jid' => 1]
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Results**

```
 "hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "job_id" : 1,
      "sourced" : 0
    }
  }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That worked for me thanks @Assael but I had to do 1 more thing for version 7.5.  Check if    doc['fieldname'].size() > 0    even before accessing    .value.